# Transactional service layer method doesn't commit changes to the db

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my Spring boot app, I have several service layers for different object (such as group, user, etc.) All these service layers are @Transactional.

I use JPA for my repositories:

```
public interface InvitationRepository extends JpaRepository<Invitation, Long> {
    public Invitation findById(long id);
}
```

in a service layer, I have the following method:

```
public void accept(long invitationId, String username) {
    Invitation invitation = this.loadById(invitationId);
    User invitee = userService.loadByUsername(username);
    Group group = invitation.getGroup();
    groupService.addMember(group.getId(), invitee.getId());
    invitee.addMemberGroup(group);
    invitee.removeReceivedInvitation(invitation);
    User inviter = userService.loadById(invitation.getInviter().getId());
    inviter.removeOwnedInvitation(invitation);
    invitationRepository.delete(invitation);
}
```

I debugged this code, while looking at the database. It should work fine, but there is no change on the db. Any reason why I don't see the change in the db, in spite of using @Transactional for my service layer?

**Update 1**

```
@Configuration
public class ProductionDataSourceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Profile("!test")
    public BasicDataSource productionDataSource() throws URISyntaxException {
        URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));
        String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
        String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
        String dbUrl = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s%s?useSSL=false", dbUri.getHost(),  dbUri.getPath());
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
        basicDataSource.setUsername(username);
        basicDataSource.setPassword(password);
        return basicDataSource;
    }   
}
```

Comment: may you post also your spring context configuration?

Comment: This is a spring boot application. Do you want the datasource config ?

Comment: Yes and also the transaction manager configuration

Comment: I updated the post with the data source configuration. I don't have any transaction manager configuration. I have entities such as Group, User, etc. and I use annotation to define relation between entities. (e.g.  @JoinTable(name = "GROUP_USER", 
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id"), 
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MEMBER_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")) )

Comment: are you sure you are using this datasource configuration? May you change the bean name in `dataSource` that is `@Bean("dataSource")`

Comment: Set the log level to debug for the following packages:
- org.springframework.orm
- org.springframework.transaction
and then check the logs.

Comment: @AngeloImmediata yes I'm sure I'm using it

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Do I have to have a transaction manager configuration ? could it be the reason it's not working as expected ?

Comment: Well actually I’ll say a not very popular thing.... I’m not at all fan of spring boot so I always use spring.... in my configurations classes and/or xml files I always have a transaction manager configuration... according to me it’s real that spring boot is fast but it hides too many thing and I like having full control....